# Uploading a file on a URL

Tags: unix, curl

Can anyone help me to find out a unix command that is used to upload/download a file on/from an URL?
Particular URL in which i'm trying to upload/download is protected with an user id and password. 
I guess curl serves this purpose but not aware of how to use it? Could you please give me sugegstions on this?

Comment: "upload to a URL" is too generic term to be able to answer to without a lot of more details... I guess you mean HTTP? Are you "emulating" a form submission perhaps? how does the form look like? how does the user+password "protection" work?

Answer (score 0):

curl has a command line argument named -d (for data) and you can use it like this to send a file(you need to add a @ before a file-name to have curl treat it as a file and not a value:

```
curl -X POST -d @myfilename http://example.com/upload
```

You can add multiple -d arguments if you need to send a FORM value along with your file. Like so:

```
curl -X POST -d @myfilename -d name=MyFile http://example.com/upload
```

Comment: thanks Jason... But i need to pass username and password to open that url .. how can i pass username and password through this command?

Comment: You can use `http://username:password@example.com` if the server supports basic authentication, or if it supports form based authentication then you need to establish a session (possibly by visiting the site in a browser and logging in) and then passing the session keys as extra data with -d or look into the `--cookie` option